# Hensel's Lemma and direct formula: Why can one set a single $\overline{f'(a)}$ for all j's in $a_{j+1} = a_j - f(a_j)\overline{f'(a)}$

Tags: number-theory, self-learning

[In lecture 7 of MIT's Theory of Numbers](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec7.pdf) there is a method of (using Hensel's Lemma) finding solutions for $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j+1}}$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], f(a) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p^j}$ and $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Let $a_j$ be a root of $f(x) \pmod{p^j}$, then $a_{j+1}=a_j - f(a_j)\overline{f'(a)} \pmod{p^{j+1}}$ is a root of $f(x) \pmod{p^{j+1}}$. It is written that one can choose for all j's single $\overline{f'(a)}$ such that $f'(a)\overline{f'(a)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Then $f(a_j) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^j}$ for $j \ge 1$ as long as $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
Why can one choose only one $\overline{f'(a)}$ for, say $j = 1$, and use it for all j's? Or why does $f(a_j) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^j}$ for $j \ge 1$ hold?

Comment: Isn’t $f(a_j)$ already $\equiv0\pmod{p^j}\,$? Then what you need to multiply $f(a_j)$ by is only important modulo $p$, that is, two things congruent modulo $p$ will give the same result modulo $p^{j+1}$.

Comment: You know that $f$ has a derivative $f'(a)$ but what does that mean? You get from $a_1$ to $a_2$ but now what do you need to get to $a_3$?

Comment: @Somos I edited the question to make it more complete. More complete statement is in the linked lecture note of the course.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I did not notice before that $a_{j+1} \equiv a_j \pmod{p}$ by Hensel. Hence $f'(a_{j+1}) \equiv f'(a_j) \pmod{p}$. It follow that their inverses are also congruent $\pmod{p}$. Often I miss such things that one should immediately understand, I feel time to time I am too slow...